# How do I get Ruby set up in OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I've decided to start experimenting with Ruby to get out of my little Java box, and want to start with a little personal project taking some written addresses and geocodes them.

As a start, I got the [Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) and started messing about with them from the command line, just using Ruby as installed in OS X (ruby -version returns 1.8.7).  So far, so good.  Then I used `gem install geocoder`, which worked nicely.  But to work with some of it's objects, it needs json, so on to `gem install json` when...

```
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
      /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/sharakan/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sharakan/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/json-1.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sharakan/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/json-1.7.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

The gem_make.out file just has the same mkmf.rb error.

After doing a bit of searching, I found that people with similar sounding problems found resolution by installing XCode.  I haven't seen my XCode DVD in a long time, and the version available from Apple now requires 10.7.

I also found some information that made [RVM](https://rvm.io/) sound like it might solve the problem.  But sadly that too failed with compilation problems:

```
[2012-06-11 20:50:00]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/sharakan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/sharakan/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/sharakan/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

So where to go next?  Do I really need to purchase Lion to get Ruby working on my machine?

Comment: Check homebrew and rbenv. I think `brew doctor` should set you up for installing rbenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue that you don't have xcode installed, you really just need make, gcc, etc installed.

The easiest way to do this to just use [OS X GCC Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)

Installing that should get you on your way.

Comment: Worked like a charm, and so much smaller than the XCode 3.x installer that I finally found on Apple's Dev site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get a Snow Leopard version of Xcode/Developer Tools from the Apple developer site. You might also want to look into [Xcode, GCC and Homebrew](http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html), from Kenneth Reitz: standalone GCC tools without Xcode. There is also an official Apple offshoot, although that may be Lion only.

Comment: That CLI tool set from Apple looks like just what I want, but is in fact only for Lion, as you suspected.

Comment: There is https://github.com/downloads/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/GCC-10.6.pkg for SL.

Comment: Ruby is not yet fully ready for `clang` / `LLVM` and this are compilers provided by **Xcode 4.2+**, you need Xcode 4.1 or osx-gcc-installer which provides `gcc-4.2` a **GNU** version of `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try RailsInstaller for OSX which includes RVM, Ruby, Rails and most important libraries that are needed for ruby, you can download it here https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-nix/downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Use RVM to install ruby. I highly recommend using RVM, especially if you are going to possibly have multiple projects that may use different versions of Ruby (or even JRuby!)

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: Yeah, but RVM gave me the other errors as I mentioned in the question.